# Unclear simplification step in bifurcation analysis of first-order system from Strogatz

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

I am going through the examples in "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos 2ed" (Strogatz 2015) and I don't understand the simplification step for the solution to example 3.2.1. Why is it that the resulting first order system is

\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = x -\ ...
\end{equation}

instead of

\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = x(1 - x^2) -\ ...
\end{equation}
after the **and so**? I understand the Taylor expansion, but the simplification of $x(1-x^2)$ to $x$ isn't clear to me. My thought is that because $x$ is close to zero, one might simply ignore the $(1-x^2)$ term in $x(1-x^2)$, but then again, if that is possible, why not just ignore the whole term and say that $x(1-x^2) \approx 0$?

[image]

Comment: It looks like he is keeping terms up to quadratic order. Then $x (1 - x^2) = x - x^3 = x + O (x^3)$.

Comment: I see. So by expanding $x(1-x^2)$, the resulting $x^3$  is already captured by the $O(x^3)$ term, and thus $x^3$ can be excluded, leaving only $x$ behind?

Comment: Correct. Note that there are also $O (x^3)$ terms in the Taylor expansion of the exponential; those are grouped together with the $-x^3$ from the $x (1 - x^2)$.